# MySQL Update Lefl Join Error #1064

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, left-join

I have following query:

```
UPDATE `order_tab`
LEFT JOIN `currency_tab`
ON (`order_tab`.`order_actual_loading_date` = `currency_tab`.`currency_date`)
SET `order_tab`.`order_cost_converted` = (`order_tab`.`order_cost_pricelist` * `currency_tab`.`currency_value`);
```

After running I have error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'LEFT JOIN `currency_tab`
>   ON (`order_tab`.`order_actual_loading_date` = `order_c' at line 2

MySQL version:

```
+---------------+-------------+
| Variable_name | Value       |
+---------------+-------------+
| version       | 3.23.52-log |
+---------------+-------------+
```

order_tab

```
+---------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| order_id                        | int(10) unsigned |      | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id                         | int(10) unsigned |      |     | 0       |                |
| order_loading_address           | blob             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_loading_city              | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_unloading_address         | blob             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_unloading_city            | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_desc                      | blob             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_collect_date_start        | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_collect_date_end          | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_delivery_date             | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_cost_pricelist            | float(11,2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_currency_pricelist        | varchar(6)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_cost_forwarder            | float(11,2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_currency_forwarder        | varchar(6)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_cost_converted            | float(11,2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_currency_converted        | varchar(6)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_distance                  | float(11,2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_activation_date           | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_state                     | int(2) unsigned  |      |     | 0       |                |
| order_notes                     | blob             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_date                      | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_payer                     | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_receiver                  | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_forwarder                 | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_forwarder_car_no          | varchar(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_forwarder_contact_address | blob             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_forwarder_trailer_no      | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_reservation_date          | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_assortment                | varchar(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_weight                    | float(6,3)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_group                     | int(2) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_type                      | int(2) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_invoice_no                | varchar(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_closing_date              | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_actual_loading_date       | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_actual_unloading_date     | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order_company_offerer           | varchar(11)      |      |     |         |                |
| objversion                      | timestamp(14)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

currency_tab

```
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| currency_date  | date       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| currency_value | float(6,4) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**How can I avoid this error?**

Comment: `order_currency.currency_date` perhaps it should be `currency_tab.currency_date`

Comment: I corrected SQL, but still the same.

Comment: Please provide the table structures into the question.

Comment: If the table name and column names are correct then the query looks good, may be you have a hidden character somewhere in the query  ?

Comment: I checked  everything, no hidden character. Does MySQL 3.23 support UPDATE JOIN? Maybe here is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work:

```
UPDATE `order_tab`, `currency_tab`
SET `order_tab`.`order_cost_converted` = (`order_tab`.`order_cost_pricelist` * `currency_tab`.`currency_value`)
WHERE (`order_tab`.`order_actual_loading_date` = `currency_tab`.`currency_date`)
```

OR [recommended]

```
UPDATE `order_tab`
SET `order_tab`.`order_cost_converted` = (`order_tab`.`order_cost_pricelist` * (SELECT `currency_tab`.`currency_value` FROM `currency_tab` 
WHERE `order_tab`.`order_actual_loading_date` = `currency_tab`.`currency_date`))
```

> **NOTE :**
>   Using `LEFT JOIN` makes `currency_tab`.`currency_value` sometimes NULL

Comment: Unfortunetly all code doen't work. Problem is, that MySQL 3.23 doen't support UPDATE multi tables.

[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/update.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/update.html)
`... Starting with MySQL 4.0.4, you can also perform UPDATE operations covering multiple tables. ...`